# Infinity scroll vuetify

Tags: vuejs3, vuetify.js

The application for working with the TMDB API makes a request for popular movies if the search string is empty, or for the search string. Implemented dynamic loading with Infinity scroll vuetify. Everything works correctly, except for the case when initially no films were found. In this case, the call from the template does not automatically work, and, probably, the solution to this problem is to call this function from watch.  although everything works correctly. What is the correct way to call this method?

```
<template>
   <v-infinite-scroll :onLoad="loadFilms" :films="films" color="indigo">
        <v-container>
            <v-row align="center">
                <v-col v-for="film in films"
                       :key="film.id"
                       xl="2"
                       lg="3"
                       md="4"
                       sm="6"
                       xs="12">
                    <film :film="film"></film>
                </v-col>
            </v-row>
        </v-container>
    </v-infinite-scroll>
</template>

<script>
import CinemaService from "@/components/CinemaService";
import _ from "lodash";
import Film from "@/components/Film.vue";
import {useGenresStore} from "@/store/GenresStore";

export default {
    name: "Index",

    data() {
        return {
            films: [],
            term: "",
            page: 0,
            service: new CinemaService(),
            errorDialog: false,
            errorDialogMessage: "",
            genresStore: useGenresStore()
        };
    },

    components: {
        Film
    },

    mounted() {
        this.loadGenres();
    },

    watch: {
        term: _.debounce(async function () {
            this.films = [];
            this.page = 0;
            await this.loadFilms(() => {});
        }, 500)
    },

    methods: {
        async api() {
            return new Promise(resolve => {
                this.page += 1;

                if (!this.term) {
                    this.service.loadPopularsFilms(this.page).then(response => {
                        resolve(response.data.results);
                    }).catch(() => this.showErrorDialog("Не удалось загрузить фильмы"))
                } else {
                    this.service.loadSearchingFilms(this.term, this.page).then(response => {
                        resolve(response.data.results);
                    }).catch(() => this.showErrorDialog("Не удалось загрузить фильмы"))
                }
            });
        },

        async loadFilms({done}) {
            const onOnePageFilms = await this.api();

            if (onOnePageFilms.length === 0) {
                done("empty");
            } else {
                this.films.push(...onOnePageFilms);
                done("ok");
            }
        },

        loadGenres() {
            this.service.loadGenres().then(response => {
                this.genresStore.genres = response.data.genres;
            }).catch(() => this.showErrorDialog("Не удалось загрузить наименования жанров"))
        },

        showErrorDialog(errorDialogMessage) {
            this.errorDialogMessage = errorDialogMessage;
            this.errorDialog = true;
        }
    }
};
</script>
```